# Bootstrap modal inside smaller modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, opencart, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible to get a Bootstrap modal to show a larger modal?

I found examples like [this](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/) that show stackable modals, but they all show the larger modal opening the smaller one, while I need the small modal to open the large one.

I am working on a shipping cost calculator extension for OpenCart. OpenCart shows the list of shipping options coming from my extension in a modal. I want the user to be able to click on each option and see a larger modal with the detailed itemized list of the selected shipping option. I have no control over the modal with the list of options, but I can put some html in the text of the option and make it clickable and make it toggle a second modal.

Right now I have a small dialog with 2-3 bullet items, and each item has a clickable green i that opens a dialog that sometimes doesn't even fit in the screen and has a scrollbar. Using the scrollbar is acceptable when the modal is large, but this modal is as small as the one with the 2-3 bullet options.

First modal with 2 bullets:
[image: First modal with 2 bullets]

Second modal with description the selected bullet:
[image: Second modal with description the selected bullet]